# Moving an object along a path with constant speed

Tags: unity-game-engine, opengl, graphics, 3d, directx

I have an object path composed by a polyline (3D point array) with points VERY unevenly distributed. I need to move an object at constant speed using a timer with interval set at 10 ms.

Unevenly distributed points produce variable speed to the human eye. So now I need to decide how to treat this long array of 3D points.

The first idea I got was to subdivide long segments in smaller parts. It works better but where points are jam-packed the problem persists.

What's the best approach in these cases? Another idea, could be to simplify the original path using [Ramer–Douglas–Peucker algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm), then to subdivide it evenly again but I'm not sure if it will fully resolve my problem.

This should be a fairly common problem in many areas of the 3D graphics, so does a proven approach exist?

Comment: but if the object is moving on a constant speed, it won't depend on the distance between points, no? More points will only affect perception on "smooth" changes like curves, but should not on speed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a JavaScript pen for you https://codepen.io/dawken/pen/eYpxRmN?editors=0010 but it should be very similar in any other language. Click on the rect to add points.

You have to maintain a time dependent `distance` with constant speed, something like this:

```
const t = currentTime - startTime;
const distance = (t * speed) % totalLength;
```

Then you have to find the two points in the path such that the current distance is intermediate between the *"distance"* on the path; you store the *"distance from start of the path"* on each point `{x, y, distanceFromStart}`. The first point `points[i]` such that `distance < points[i].distanceFromStart` is your destination; the point before that `points[i - 1]` is your source. You need to interpolate linearly between them.

Assuming that you have **no duplicate points** (otherwise you get a division by zero) you could do something like this.

```
for (let i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
  if (distance < points[i].distanceFromStart) {

    const pFrom = points[i - 1];
    const pTo = points[i];
    const f = (distance - pFrom.distanceFromStart) / (pTo.distanceFromStart- pFrom.distanceFromStart);
    const x = pFrom.x + (pTo.x - pFrom.x) * f;
    const y = pFrom.y + (pTo.y - pFrom.y) * f;
    ctx.fillRect(x - 1, y - 1, 3, 3);
    break;
  }
}
```

See this pen. Click on the rectangle to add points: https://codepen.io/dawken/pen/eYpxRmN?editors=0010

Comment: Just stumbled into a code pen made by someone else about the same topic. I am going to share it here: https://codepen.io/kaliedarik/pen/MWadEwm . Seems really cool, has curved lines. If I have time I'll add a few more details to this answer about constant speed along curves, it's another really interesting topic.